# numbering of members of a sequence

Tags: python, numbers, sequence

I need additional python codes that will number the left column of the output below like I have shown in the right column:  The codes here just divides the sequence into 3s.
Now I want to number them from 1 to the last as I have done manually in the right column.

```
cds = "atgagtgaacgtctgagcattaccccgctggggccgtatatcggcgcacaataa"

for i in range(0,len(cds),3):
     print cds[i:i+3],
... 
Atg 1
Agt 2
Gaa 3
Cgt 4
Ctg 5
Agc 6
Att 7
Acc 8
Ccg 9
Ctg 10
Ggg 11
Ccg 12
Tat 13
Atc 14
Ggc 15
Gca 16
Caa 17
Taa 18
Taa 19
```

Comment: You may also try [CG.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It is not very clear for me at least.Could you give more input so we will have ability to help you on this. What do you mean on right/left column?

Comment: Just `print cds[i:i+3], i//3+1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
cds = "atgagtgaacgtctgagcattaccccgctggggccgtatatcggcgcacaataa"

for num, i in enumerate(range(0,len(cds),3)):
    print cds[i:i+3], num + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that this is what you want, but:

```
cds = "atgagtgaacgtctgagcattaccccgctggggccgtatatcggcgcacaataa"
for data in ((i+1, cds[i:i+3], i+1) for i in xrange(0, len(cds), 3)):
    #do something
    print data
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here you may read about this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

```
>>> cds = "atgagtgaacgtctgagcattaccccgctggggccgtatatcggcgcacaataa"
>>> for ind, val in enumerate(range(0,len(cds),3), start=1):
...     print cds[val:val+3].capitalize(), ind
...
Atg 1
Agt 2
Gaa 3
Cgt 4
Ctg 5
Agc 6
Att 7
Acc 8
Ccg 9
Ctg 10
Ggg 11
Ccg 12
Tat 13
Atc 14
Ggc 15
Gca 16
Caa 17
Taa 18
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in map(lambda x,y,z: [z[0]+1,"".join([x,y,z[1]])], list(cds)[::3],list(cds)[1::3],enumerate(list(cds)[2::3])):
    print item[1].capitalize(), item[0]
```

Comment: `print '\n'.join('%s %s' % (cds[y:y+3], x) for x, y in enumerate(xrange(0, len(cds), 3), start=1))` And your variation return list of lists which can't be printed directly.

Comment: Thank you all for your responding to my question